# how to hide sections from pdf view laravel domPDF

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5.1, dompdf

I want to display only specific sections on my blade to pdf view . is it possible using DOMpdf ? pls advice

```
   public function pdf()
    {
         $pdf = PDF::loadView('home');
        return $pdf->stream();

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

why you don't create a new blade file just for your section, and you shouldn't use any kind of extending like

```
@extends('layout')
```

so you will just create the view template file which contain your section

for example if your home have that section

```
@section('topdf')
<div class="pdfsection">My PDF Goes Here</div>
@endsection
```

so you will create a new blade file for example with the name mypdf.blade.php
and let it contain the just the code

```
<div class="pdfsection">My PDF Goes Here</div>
```

then your function will be like that

```
public function pdf()
    {
         $pdf = PDF::loadView('mypdf');
        return $pdf->stream();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use media types to define a style that applies only during PDF generation. For example, a class that sets the display to none on sections you don't want included in the render.

```css
@media print {
  .noprint { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This will render to the pdf</p>
</div>

<div class="noprint">
  <p>This will not render to the pdf</p>
</div>
```

Which media type you specify depends on which one dompdf is configured to use. In a default install dompdf uses the "screen" media type. To change the media type that dompdf uses:

- In 0.6.2 or earlier set the `DOMPDF_DEFAULT_MEDIA_TYPE` configuration constant to "screen".
- In 0.7.0 or later call `$dompdf->set_option('defaultMediaType', 'print');` after instantiating dompdf.

dompdf also recognizes the "dompdf" media type, if for some reason you have some styling you only want to use when rendering to PDF with dompdf. Since this is an unofficial media type other devices should ignore it.